# Form does not check reCaptcha

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

I have a form that I want to add ReCaptcha to, however, somewhere along the line something isnt working correctly because my form will still submit whether or not reCaptcha is verified.

This is the form:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET[ 'CaptchaPass'])){ ?>
<div>Thank you! Your Form was Successfully Submitted</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if(isset($_GET[ 'CaptchaFail'])){ ?>
<div>Captcha Error. Please verify that you are human!</div>
<?php } ?>
<form action="http://vmobileautoglass.com/php/func_contact.php">
    <label>Name</label> <span class="color-red">*</span>
    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-0">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <label>Email
        <span class="color-red">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-0">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <label>Phone

    </label>
    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-0">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone">
        </div>
    </div>
    <label>Message</label> <span class="color-red">*</span>
    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-0">
            <textarea rows="8" class="form-control" name="message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MYSITEKEYFROMGOOGLE"></div>
    <p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="ContactButton">Send Message</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

This goes at the very top of the page where the form is located:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['ContactButoon'])) {

    $url = 'https://google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $privatekey = "MYPRIVATEKEYFROMGOOGLE";

    $response = file_get_contents($url . "?secret=" . $privatekey . "&response=" . $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $date = json_decode($response);

    if (isset($data->success) AND $data->success == true) {
        header('Location: contact.php?CaptchaPasss=True');
    } else {
        header('Location: contact.php?CaptchaFail=True');
    }
}
?>
```

And this is the forms functionality:

```
// Receiving variables
@$pfw_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
@$name = addslashes($_GET['name']);
@$email = addslashes($_GET['email']);
@$phone = addslashes($_GET['phone']);
@$message = addslashes($_GET['message']);

// Validation
if (strlen($name) == 0) {
    header("Location: http://vmobileautoglass.com/php/err_name.php");
    exit;
}

if (strlen($email) == 0) {
    header("Location: http://vmobileautoglass.com/php/err_email.php");
    exit;
}

if (strlen($message) == 0) {
    header("Location: http://vmobileautoglass.com/php/err_message.php");
    exit;
}

//Sending Email to form owner
$pfw_header = "From: $email\n"
        . "Reply-To: $email\n";
$pfw_subject = "vMobile Contact Form";
$pfw_email_to = "vmobileag@gmail.com";
$pfw_message = "Visitor's IP: $pfw_ip\n"
        . "name: $name\n"
        . "email: $email\n"
        . "phone: $phone\n"
        . "message: $message\n";
@mail($pfw_email_to, $pfw_subject, $pfw_message, $pfw_header);

header("Location: http://vmobileautoglass.com/php/successform.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
  $date = json_decode($response);

    if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true){
```

$date should be $data.

Comment: Thank you. Fixed, but the problem persists.

Comment: Please provide more info, is the $response variable an array?